# Moving from local to server Yii

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-extensions, yii-components, yii2-model

I have configured(installed successfully) on my WAMP in Local and is working fine.

When I uploaded it to my server, it doesn't work. I have edited only "config/db.php" as per requirement.
Now I browse to my webpage that is http://www.office.lnjcollege.in, the login page appeared by placing username and password. However after clicking on login option it says that "the webpage is not available" or "err_empty_response".

one can check by username="admin" and password="admin".

Note: while I run `office.lnjcollege.in/edusec-requirements.php` then it says "Conclusion
Congratulations! Your server configuration satisfies all requirements"
but when I run
"office.lnjcollege.in/requirements.php" it says "Conclusion-
Your server configuration satisfies the minimum requirements by this application. Please pay attention to the warnings listed below and check if your application will use the corresponding features."

Answer (score 0):

Your website is working properly!

You are entering a wrong URL. exclude the `www` subdomain.

http://office.lnjcollege.in/edusec-requirements.php

http://office.lnjcollege.in/

Comment: thanks for your response. but after "log in" page, does not redirect to the proper page and displays error. check by username-admin, password- digital847404

Comment: That's a different question, my friend. You should ask a separate one about the software you're using: EduSec